# javascript grouping mechanism for different Id

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to get the values of 9 labels and put them together to label 10 which is the result. To elaborate my statement I'll show this example

LABEL1:The
LABEL2:quick
LABEL3:brown
LABEL4:fox
LABEL5:jump
LABEL6:over
LABEL7:the
LABEL8:lazy
LABEL9:dog.

LABEL10(result): The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog.

I decided to put them all in one class(build) and put them in one holder to hold the values(holder). However instead of displaying the output it displays this [object NodeList]. I never really like using the for loop and avoid it if I can, however my classmates said it is the easiest way to solve my problem so I tried it. How can I imporve my code to finish the task.

Here's my code:
Updated

```
var result  = document.getElementById('formatted_text');
        var values = result.getElementsByTagName('label');

        for (var i = 0; i<10;i++)
        {
            var getvalue = document.getElementbyClass('build');
           //sir I'm not sure on what to put on this part, but I think this is the part were I get the string input
        }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Comment: Well, `[object NodeList]` is the *default string representation* of a node list. `getElementsByTagName` returns a *list of DOM elements*. How can the engine know *how* exactly you want to convert those DOM elements to string values? You have to iterate over the node list and extract the information you want. And I think your classmate probably meant that you should use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of `nodeList` (not that you should put the whole code into a loop).

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of Node (that's why there is a `s` at `Elements`). And your third line seems useless.

Comment: yes sir I'll update it

Comment: Just take a look at the [MDN `getElementsByTagName` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) for an example of how to iterate over a node list.

Comment: thank you for the link sir I'll try it and post my update\

Comment: Just a few things problematic with your code:
1. There are two variables with really similar names: nodelist and nodeList...Don't do that, it's confusing. You can name the first one index, for example.
2. In the second line of the loop, you're overwriting you variable "nodeList" you define in the first loop line.
3. You're not using the loop at whole, no changes in each iteration.

Comment: sir I updated my code, I'll appreciate it if you give your opinions again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code:

```
var result  = document.getElementById('formatted_text');
    var labels = result.getElementsByTagName('label');
    var value="";
    for (var i = 0; i<labels.length;i++)
    {
        if(i==9){
            labels[i].innerHTML=value;
        }else{
            value += " "+labels[i].innerHTML;                       
        }

    }
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9VUd/2/)